# Is it possible to intercept logcat-messages or configure logcat to persist to file?

Tags: android, logging, logcat, slf4j, logback

I need to persist my android applications log messages and are considering these solutions:

1. Using SLF4J with Logback. Does this solution cover 3rdparty libraries if they are not using SLF4J? Can we work around this issue?
2. Intercept logcat-messages from my app before getting to logcat and persist the messages. Is it possible?
3. Configure logcat to persist to file as well as buffer. Is it possible?
4. Create a async task or a new application that filters all the log-messages and persists them to file. This should work, but might be a workaround?

Does anyone have a solution for the above, or got another solution?